# How can I format MacBook hard drive from OSX install disc?

Tags: macos, mac, reinstall, refit

I did some research and I found that rEFIt makes the OSX install disc nit recognize a Tiger partition. I've read that the solution includes backing up and then formatting. I am going to do this sans the backup. How can I format the drive using an OSX? Will this the Tiger fix the issue of the installer not seeing partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the disk utility in the menu bar on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an erase and install from the Tiger disk which will restore everything back to scratch.